# Can one find elliptic curve and a point of known order over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $n$ be composite with unknown factorization.

Can one efficiently find elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
and a point $P$ on $E$ of known order $m > 5$?

$P$ should be nontorsion when lifted to $\mathbb{Q}$, so to avoid
such cases one may consider $m$ larger.

$E$ might be singular (though better not be).

---

What I know

Singular cases like $E : y^2 = x^3$ are easy.

Singular cases when there is an isomorphism to a multiplicative
subgroup are easy if one knows an element of known multiplicative
order (say for Mersenne numbers), but this
doesn't work for general $n$.

Tried division polynomials, but this leads to solving nonlinear
equation over the ring so didn't work for me.

Subquestions

> Are there $n$ of special form (except the described) for which it
>   is possible?

The problem is not harder than factoring.

> Is the non-singular case as hard as factoring?

Comment: You are not very precise with your terminology. If I understand correctly: Given $n$ and $m>5$, you want a Weierstrass equation $E$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ and a point $P$ of infinite order in $E(\mathbb{Q})$ such that it has non-singular reduction modulo $n$ and it is of order $m$ in the reduction. Is that it ?

Comment: To say that $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ means that it is a Weierstrass equation whose discriminant is invertiable modulo $n$. Note also that usually you can't lift points from modulo $n$ to the integers.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich thanks for the comments. First, $m$ is not given, you are free to choose it (though arbitrary $m$ of course is better). Second, P need not be in E(Q) (though it might be), it must be in E(Z/nZ), i.e. after the reduction mod n. To avoid non-invertible denominator one can work with projective points after homogenization of the Weirstrass model. I mention the torsion because a rational torsion point will work for all $n$.

Comment: Ah! So given $n$, you want to find a Weierstrass equation $E$ over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with a non-singular point $P$ on it whose order in $E(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is larger than $5$. That is easy by the Hasse-Weil bound, isn't it? So I probably still do not understand the question. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich you understood exactly. I am not an expert but this is hard for me. Note that I can't do point counting to compute the order since the factorization of $n$ is unknown. And I can't construct curves of given order over Z/nZ. It is easy if $n$ were prime.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Just to clarify: Besides E and P you must find the order $m$ too.

Comment: Sorry that I am still confused. Is this formulation correct: Given $n$. You wish to find an algorithm that returns a Weierstrass equation $E$ over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, a point $P$ on $E$ and a integer $m>5$ such that $P$ has order $m$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, picking a random $E$ and $P$, leaves you with the problem to determine the order. But how about fixing $m=7$. The family of elliptic curves with a $7$-torsion point has an explicit equation.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Exactly. With the exception that rational torsion point over Q works for all $n$, so in theory the algorithm should work for $m$ larger than the maximum Q torsion.  The algorithm should be efficient -- if I know the factors of $n$ I know an algorithm for all admissible $m$.

Comment: Finding explicit equations for elliptic curves with a given $m$-torsion points is done by looking for descriptions of $X_1(m)$. This can be done for small $m$ both for $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (at least if $m$ is coprime to $n$). I don't understand what $\mathbb{Q}$ should have to do with your question.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Many thanks! I begin to understand parts of your ideas. All the best!